# How to define a matrix-matrix multiplication so that it works for vectorXvector, vectorXmatrix, and matrixXvector as well?

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operator-overloading, derived-class

I have defined a matrix class `class MyMatrix` and a member function `MyMatrix operator*(const MyMatrix & B)const;`  But this function only works for `MyMatrix * MyMatrix`. I want to extend the scope of this definition so that it can also be used for `vector<double> * MyMatrix`, `MyMatrix * vector<double>`, and `vector<double> * vector<double>` (for both inner and outer product). What should I do to achieve this if I do not want to define another class for vector? I guess there is a way to automatically convert `vector<double>` to `MyMatrix` when this function is called. But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: "for both inner and outer product" and how do you know which `*` does what?

Comment: @n.m.   I meant it ought to work for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically convert `vector<double>` to `MyMatrix` then define a constructor for `MyMatrix` that takes `vector<double>` as a parameter and constructs a matrix from that vector. This won't completely solve your problem though, since you need to take care of the difference between row vector and column vector. You can also overload the * operator to take a vector and MyMatrix in any order, and a vector and a vector. Something like:

```
MyMatrix operator*(const vector<double>& v, const MyMatrix& m);
```

etc.

Comment: make it `friend` too.

Comment: But the return value in your definition is MyMatrix, while vector * matrix should result in a vector instead. Is there any way that I can avoid defining any conversion between vector<double> and MyMatrix and all the functions can work in a wanted way?

Comment: Well if you want the return value to be a vector make it a vector instead. It's up to you how you want to design your class and the operations. I'm just addressing what's possible to do in c++ with operator overloading. The rest is up to you.

Comment: @grigor Should it be a member function of MyMatrix ?

Comment: @macroland Why do I need make it a friend function?

Comment: @JTK the only operators you can make a member of MyMatrix are those whose first argument is MyMatrix.

Comment: @grigor Is there something like a move constructor so that when I use vector<double> as the argument whose type ought to be MyMatrix then the compiler can automatically convert vector<double> to MyMatrix?